# Something between std::array and std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, containers

In my code, I use `std::vector`s a lot. I read the size of the constainers and assign corresponding values. No `push_back`s are involved so `std::vector` gives me more than I want. I also do not want to use native C-arrays due to safety issues. Also, `std::array` requires size of the container in advance. I am looking for something that is very close to `std::array` but its size could be able to change just once as we do for native C-arrays: define a pointer and then allocate memory.

Comment: There was a proposal for [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray), but it didn't make it into C++14.

Comment: @juanchopanza whatever happened to `bs_array`?

Comment: You don't _have_ to call `push_back` if you don't want to, y'know..